# Cannot read property 'containerColor' of undefined (Making reactnative custom component)

Tags: javascript, react-native, custom-component

Im trying to create my own react native component when I ran into this problem.

> Cannot read property 'containerColor' of undefined
>
> Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling
>   runApplication)

I import this component to my app.js where i supply the props. I dont know what else to do.

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

export default class TreeViewBasic extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    <View
      style={[
        Styles.container,
        this.props.selected ? Styles.oNBg : Styles.ofFBg
      ]}
    >
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.onPress}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Text style={this.props.selected ? Styles.oNColor : Styles.ofFColor}>
            {this.props.name}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>;
  }
}

export const Styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 4, //4 out of 5
    elevation: 2,
    alignSelf: "flex-end",
    height: 40
  },
  ofFColor: {
    color: "darkgray"
  },
  oNColor: {
    color: "black"
  },
  ofFBg: {
    backgroundColor: "gray"
  },
  oNBg: {
    backgroundColor: this.props.containerColor
  }
});

TreeViewBasic.defaultProps = {
  selected: false,
  containerColor: "white"
};

TreeViewBasic.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onPress: PropTypes.func,
  selected: PropTypes.bool,
  containerColor: PropTypes.string
};
```

What is wrong or lacking? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access `props` outside of the context. Use `StyleSheet.flatten` to deal with dynamic styles.

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

export default class TreeViewBasic extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    const {containerColor} = this.props;
    // dynamic style
    const dynamicBG = StyleSheet.flatten([Styles.oNBg, {
      backgroundColor: containerColor
    }];

    <View
      style={[
        Styles.container,
        this.props.selected ? dynamicBG : Styles.ofFBg
      ]}
    >
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.onPress}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Text style={this.props.selected ? Styles.oNColor : Styles.ofFColor}>
            {this.props.name}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>;
  }
}

export const Styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 4, //4 out of 5
    elevation: 2,
    alignSelf: "flex-end",
    height: 40
  },
  ofFColor: {
    color: "darkgray"
  },
  oNColor: {
    color: "black"
  },
  ofFBg: {
    backgroundColor: "gray"
  },
  oNBg: {
    backgroundColor: "transparent" // default color
  }
});

TreeViewBasic.defaultProps = {
  selected: false,
  containerColor: "white"
};

TreeViewBasic.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onPress: PropTypes.func,
  selected: PropTypes.bool,
  containerColor: PropTypes.string
};
```